# Unable to resolve 'download.nodesource.com'

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

Whenever I run `sudo apt-get update`, I always get this error

```
Err:1 https://download.nodesource.com focal InRelease
Could not resolve 'download.nodesource.com'
```

This is the warning that I get at the end of the process

```
W: Failed to fetch https://download.nodesource.com/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not resolve 'download.nodesource.com'
```

I tried searching for the error on google to no vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like NodeSource has removed their DNS record for the "download" subdomain. This means you'll need to remove (or disable) the repository from your sources list.

Assuming you're using the Desktop version of Ubuntu, you can do it like this:

0. Open "Software & Updates":
   [image: Software & Updates]
1. Select the "Other Software" tab:
   [image: Other Software]
2. Uncheck the record for download.nodesource.com
3. Press "close" and update apt

Comment: I am actually using lightdm, using gdm is causing a login loop. Hence, can't find "Software & Updates"

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppas-quick-tip/ this helped me